# WiX Msi not creating a folder in install path when installed from a Bundle in Release Configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

I have an Exe package created using WiX Toolset with 7 MSIs bundled inside. I create 7 folders in the Installation path. One folder for each MSIs. When I build my WiX Bootstrapper project (Bundle) with Configuration==Debug, using Visual Studio 2015, and on installing the Output Exe package(MySetup.exe) everything works fine. All the 7 folders are being created in my Installation Path.

But when I build with Configuration==Release,  and on installing the Output Exe package, there are only 6 folders created in my Installation Path. A particular Msi is not creating its folder that it is supposed to create. Upon examining the log files I found nothing significant. Both the Log files (Debug and Release) are similar in both **MySetup.exe** log and **MyProblematicMsi** log.

Here is my Exe package log file in [Debug](http://www.filedropper.com/debugexelog) Configuration and [Release](http://www.filedropper.com/releaseexelog) Configuration.

Also I have attached my problematic Msi package log file in [Debug](http://www.filedropper.com/debugmsilog) and [Release](http://www.filedropper.com/releasemsilog) Configuration.

How can I figure out this contrasting behaviour?

Comment: Can you add the wixproj? The configuration part...

Comment: I have added my wixproj configuration file in the following link http://www.filedropper.com/kambanfasbootstrapper

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, the wixproj of the related MSI.

Comment: I have uploaded it in the following link http://www.filedropper.com/kambanfasservicebussetup

Comment: Did you try to install on clean environment?

Comment: Issue solved. There was this Transformer.xslt file which was included in the build which was completely unnecessary. On removing that file, it worked.

Comment: I am glad to know that you resolve the issue, please post a reply and mark it as answer, it will be beneficial to other communities who have the similar issue.

Comment: Note that if files need to be uploaded to a file locker in order to illustrate a problem, a Stack Overflow question that points to them is off-topic. Please try to keep your questions self-contained, so they can remain open.